# Using dlang in a scripting sense

Tags: d

So I was just taking a look at the example posted on the dlang website here: http://dlang.org/rdmd.html and was looking to do something like the second version where you define `#!/usr/bin/env rdmd` as the first line of your file. I copied and pasted the exact copy of what they have there just to try it out and everytime I try to do `./myprog.d` I get: `: No such file or directory`

What am I missing here? If I run `rdmd ./myprog.d` it works just fine so I know rdmd is in the proper path

Comment: did you also make the file executable? `chmod +x myprog.d`, though if you didn't I think the error would b e permission denied rather than no such file... another thing to check is if the `/usr/bin/env` command actually runs on your system. You might be better off just putting the direct path to your rdmd in there like `#!/home/me/dmd2/linux/bin32/rdmd` is how I'd do it on my computer.

Comment: It is executable (774) and `/usr/bin/env` is on my system and I can do `/usr/bin/env rdmd myproog.d` and it works fine. Putting the absolute path does not work as bash complains that its a bad interpreter.

Comment: hmm it might be trying to run the 32 bit version on a 64 bit system or vice versa... in fact I'm almost certain that's the problem, that gives "no such file or directory" because the /lib/ld-Linux for the bittiness isn't there. So the fix would be maybe just deleting the one so it forces the use of the other from the path

Comment: "smells" like rdmd is not in your path.

Comment: `echo $PATH`:
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/me/.local/bin:/home/me/bin`
`which rdmd`:
`/usr/bin/rdmd`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is nice(hard) one. I like this kind of issues. You have wrong newline delimeter, probally \r\n instead of \n

Comment: Thanks a bunch, turns out I forgot to mark unix style endings cause I was editing this on my windows machine over a network share.

Comment: This was one of reasons Why I almost doesn't finish my university (bad newlines in makefile :)).

Answer (score 1):

Some Unixen have env in `/bin`, others in `/usr/bin`. Find where yours is by executing `which env`. Then use that one.